# Any problem with this strain gauge configuration to increase resolution?

Tags: strain-gage

I'm new to using strain gauges, but I've seen the typical 1, 2, and 4 strain gauge wheatstone bridge configurations. Using the diagram below, I'm referring to where R3 is a gauge, or R3 and R4, or all are gauges. Note: for this example, I'm assuming all resistances are equal when no strain is applied.

[image]

I know that if R3 and R4 are gauges and attached such that when one is under compression the other is under tension, that you get a higher resolution of the strain compared to only having a single gauge. This also helps to cancel out changes in the gauge resistance due to temperature.

My question is if R3 and R1 are gauges, where they are both attached so they see the same strain (if R1 is compressed, R3 is also compressed), this should also increase your resolution, right? Sometimes it's not feasible to have two gauges with opposing forces on them, so I thought this might be a good way to increase the resolution using two gauges when you can't configure them with opposing forces. Below is a diagram specifying the gauges just for clarification:

[image]

The problem I see if that the temperature effects will be doubled instead of canceled out (like they are when R3 and R4 are gauges), but maybe that's not a problem for some applications.

Is there a better way to increase the resolution using a second gauge when the gauges can only be attached the same surface, or if not is there any other problems with my proposed configuration? Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: IIRC, typically you would replace one of R1 or R2 with an identical strain gauge in the same place, but perpendicular to the strain, to cancel out temperature effects.

Comment: So you're saying to have R3 and R2 be strain gauges? if R2 was a gauge, but essentially not seeing a strain, then it should compensate for temperature. One case where i need to use this I care more about relative strain rather than absolute strain, so I'm really wanting to have a higher output with strain, and I think i should be able ignore the error from my temperature.

Comment: Well I mean, if you really wanted to, you could probably have all of them be strain gauges, with R4 and R2 perpendicular to R1 R3. This would remove your ability to adjust the 0 voltage and increase your dynamic range, but I think it would increase your sensitivity and still have some level of temperature compensation. There are probably other downsides to this arrangement